# How to create multiple instance of backendAddressPools, frontendports in Application Gateways through ARM template

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I am creating Application Gateways through ARM Template, reference - [Create Application Gateway v2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-application-gateway-v2-autoscale-create#create-application-gateway-v2)
I want to create multiple instances of properties for Application Gateway, i.e. "backendAddressPools", "backendHttpSettingsCollection" etc from the above template. Unable to create multiple instances thorugh "copy".

trying to implemented as per the sample provided in - [multipleinstances](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-json-samples/blob/master/azure-resource-manager/multipleinstance/multiplesecurityrules.json), showing the below error while executing in Azure DevOps pipeline.

> Unable to process template language expressions for resource
>   '/subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourceGroups/rsgAppGw/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/appGwV2'
>   at line '1' and column '2537'. 'The template function 'copyIndex' is
>   not expected at this location. The function can only be used in a
>   resource with copy specified..

azuredeploy.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Application-Vnet",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Virtual Network name"
      }
    },
    "vnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.0.0/16",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Virtual Network address range"
      }
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "ApplicationGatewaySubnet",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the subnet"
      }
    },
    "subnetPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.0.0/24",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet address range"
      }
    },
    "applicationGatewayName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "applicationGatewayV2",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Application Gateway name"
      }
    },
    "minCapacity": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 2,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Minimum instance count for Application Gateway"
      }
    },
    "frontendPort": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 80,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Application Gateway Frontend port"
      }
    },
    "backendPort": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 80,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Application gateway Backend port"
      }
    },
    "backendAddressPools": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "metadata": {
        "description": ""
      }
    },
    "backendIPAddresses": {
      "type": "array",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Back end pool ip addresses"
      }
    },
    "cookieBasedAffinity": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": ["Enabled", "Disabled"],
      "defaultValue": "Disabled",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Cookie based affinity"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "appGwPublicIpName": "[concat(parameters('applicationGatewayName'), '-pip')]",
    "appGwPublicIPRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('appGwPublicIpName'))]",
    "appGwSize": "Standard_v2",
    "subnetRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-08-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": ["[parameters('vnetAddressPrefix')]"]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('subnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetPrefix')]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-08-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "name": "[variables('appGwPublicIpName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Static"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('applicationGatewayName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('appGwPublicIPRef')]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "sku": {
          "name": "[variables('appGwSize')]",
          "tier": "Standard_v2"
        },
        "autoscaleConfiguration": {
          "minCapacity": "[parameters('minCapacity')]"
        },
        "gatewayIPConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "appGatewayIpConfig",
            "properties": {
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "frontendIPConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "appGatewayFrontendIP",
            "properties": {
              "PublicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[variables('appGwPublicIpRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "copy": [
          {
            "name": "frontendPorts",
            "count": 1,
            "input": {
              "name": "appGatewayFrontendPort",
              "properties": {
                "Port": "[parameters('frontendPort')]"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "backendAddressPools",
            "count": "[length(parameters('backendAddressPools'))]",
            "input": {
              "name": "[parameters('backendAddressPools')[copyIndex('backendAddressPools')].name]"
            },
            "copy":{
               "name":"copybackendIPAddresses",
               "count":"[length(parameters('backendIPAddresses'))]",
               "properties":{
                  "IpAddress":"[parameters('backendIPAddresses')[copyIndex('copybackendIPAddresses')].IpAddress]",
                  "fqdn":"[parameters('backendIPAddresses')[copyIndex('copybackendIPAddresses')].fqdn]"
               }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "backendHttpSettingsCollection",
            "count": 1,
            "input": {
              "name": "appGatewayBackendHttpSettings",
              "properties": {
                "Port": "[parameters('backendPort')]",
                "Protocol": "Http",
                "CookieBasedAffinity": "[parameters('cookieBasedAffinity')]"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "httpListeners",
            "count": 1,
            "input": {
              "name": "appGatewayHttpListener",
              "properties": {
                "FrontendIpConfiguration": {
                  "Id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations', parameters('applicationGatewayName'), 'appGatewayFrontendIP')]"
                },
                "FrontendPort": {
                  "Id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendPorts', parameters('applicationGatewayName'), 'appGatewayFrontendPort')]"
                },
                "Protocol": "Http"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "requestRoutingRules",
            "count": 1,
            "input": {
              "name": "rule1",
              "properties": {
                "RuleType": "Basic",
                "httpListener": {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/httpListeners', parameters('applicationGatewayName'), 'appGatewayHttpListener')]"
                },
                "backendAddressPool": {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/backendAddressPools', parameters('applicationGatewayName'), 'appGatewayBackendPool')]"
                },
                "backendHttpSettings": {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/backendHttpSettingsCollection', parameters('applicationGatewayName'), 'appGatewayBackendHttpSettings')]"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

azuredeploy.parameters.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "value": "appGwVNet"
    },
    "vnetAddressPrefix": {
      "value": "10.0.0.0/16"
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "value": "appGwSubNet1"
    },
    "subnetPrefix": {
      "value": "10.0.0.0/24"
    },
    "applicationGatewayName": {
      "value": "appGwV2"
    },
    "minCapacity": {
      "value": 1
    },
    "frontendPort": {
      "value": 80
    },
    "backendPort": {
      "value": 80
    },
    "backendAddressPools": {
      "value": [
        {
          "name": "appGatewayBackendPool1"
        },
        {
          "name": "appGatewayBackendPool2"
        },
        {
          "name": "appGatewayBackendPool3"
        }
      ]
    },
    "backendIPAddresses": {
      "value": [
        [
          {
            "IpAddress": "10.0.0.4"
          },
          {
            "IpAddress": "10.0.0.5"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "IpAddress": "10.0.0.7"
          },
          {
            "IpAddress": "10.0.0.8"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "fqdn": "mysite.com"
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    "cookieBasedAffinity": {
      "value": "Disabled"
    },
    "location": {
      "value": "centralus"
    }
  }
}
```

Want to create multiple instances of properties provided for Application Gateways.

Answer (score 2):

here's an example of what I've been doing:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
    "name": "[deployment().name]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "properties": {
        "copy": [
            {
                "name": "backendAddressPools",
                "count": "[length(parameters('backendAddressPools'))]",
                "input": {
                    "name": "[parameters('backendAddressPools')[copyIndex('backendAddressPools')].name]",
                    "properties": "[parameters('backendIPAddresses')[copyIndex('backendAddressPools')]]"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

thats just the example you need to adapt to your needs, but it showcases the idea, you need to use the copy function inside the `properties` property (doh) and define what you want to get. I've defined the `backendAddressPools` for you that should work more or less according to what I think you want (I might be wrong, so might need to tinker a bit here).

Comment: Thanks. followed as per your sample, unfortunately did not succeeded. Error- Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'properties.backendAddressPools[0].name', line 1, position 70.

Comment: I want to do for most of the properties defined in Application gateway

Comment: you are free to do that for all the properties of the application gateway, just add one object per property. updated the answer

Comment: Thanks. Partially succeeded. Trying to fix issues.

Comment: just to clarify, add another object inside "copy", it has to have name, count and input. copyIndex inside this object should point to this particular object name

Comment: update json files. Now I am struggling to retrieve IpAddress & fqdn of backendpool address.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @4c74356b41
I test it in my environment and it works with minor changes.

see following, I used it in my resources section:

```
                "copy": [
                {
                    "name": "backendAddressPools",
                    "count": "[length(parameters('backendAddressPoolsarray'))]",
                    "input": {
                        "name": "[parameters('backendAddressPoolsarray')[copyIndex('backendAddressPools')].name]",
                        "properties": {
                            "BackendAddresses": "[parameters('backendAddressPoolsarray')[copyIndex('backendAddressPools')].backendIPAddresses]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
```

This is the parameter file

```
        "backendAddressPoolsArray": {
        "value": [
            {
                "Name": "BP1",
                "backendIPAddresses": [
                    {
                        "IpAddress": "10.0.0.4"
                    },
                    {
                        "IpAddress": "10.0.0.5"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Name": "BP2",
                "backendIPAddresses": [
                    {
                        "IpAddress": "10.0.0.6"
                    },
                    {
                        "IpAddress": "10.0.0.7"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Also it doesn't need to use object, array is fine